# How can I fix JndiException on hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

This is the class I have found on this forum to provide the session factory
but I keep getting the `JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name []`

```
16:07:57,659 WARN SessionFactoryObjectFactory:98 - Could not bind factory to JNDI
```

javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:640)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:243)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:280)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper.bind(NamingHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory.addInstance(SessionFactoryObjectFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1145)
    at util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HibernateUtil is not the problem. You should look into your configuration file .cfg.xml and remove the name on the session-factory tag.

```
<session-factory name="">
```

to:

```
<session-factory>
```

This is a quick fix for that problem. The name attribute is only required to bind SessionFactory to JNDI.